# Docker - can not start mysql permission error

Tags: mysql, macos, permissions, docker, volumes

I have problem with docker and mysql. I have build an image based on *phusion/baseimage*. I want to create image where /var/lib/mysql directory is shared with my host (OS X), because I dont want to store my data on container.

Everything works fine when directory /var/lib/mysql is not shared. When I share this directory, mysql service can not start. In logs are informations about problems with permissions while starting.

Result of *ls -la* from /var/lib is:

```
[...]
drwxr-xr-x  1 lc      staff    170 Jan  3 16:55 mysql
[...]
```

The *mysql* user should be an owner. I tried to do:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql mysql/
```

But this command didn't return any error and didn't change owner.

I have also tried to add my user (from container) to mysql group:

```
lc@cbe25ac0681e:~$ groups lc
lc : lc sudo mysql
```

But It also didn't work. Have anybody any idea how to solve this issue?

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
server:
  image: lukasz619/light-core_server
  ports:
    - "40080:80"
    - "40022:22"
    - "40443:443"
    - "43306:3306"
  volumes:
     - /Users/lukasz/Workspace/database/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2

# Enable SSH
RUN rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down
RUN /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh

# public key for root
ADD public_key.pub /tmp/public_key.pub
RUN cat /tmp/public_key.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm -f /tmp/public_key.pub

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is OS X.. I ran this docker-composer.yml

```
server:
  image: lukasz619/light-core_server
  ports:
    - "40080:80"
    - "40022:22"
    - "40443:443"
    - "43306:3306"
  volumes:
      - /var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Its possible to share directories (and do *chown*) ONLY between boot2docker and container, but do not work properly shareing between Os X and container.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect this is the problem, or at least related to it, but note that the OP is using a directory under /Users that should be mounted into the VM.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you were answering your own question. You should find if you run `docker-machine ssh default` to enter the VM, your directories are mounted under `/Users`, so you can share directories between MacOS and the container (I do it all the time).

Comment: I know, and I saw /Users mounted to VM. But the problem was that I cant change any privileges in that directory. Whatever I do, I cant see any change. I can change privileges on directories shared from VM to Container (for example */var/mysql* (VM) to */var/lib/mysql* (container)).

Answer (score 0):

When we say that users are shared between the container and the host, it's not *quite* true; it's the UIDs that are actually shared. What this means is that the user named `mysql` in the container most likely has a different UID to the user `mysql` on the host.

We can try to fix this by using the image to set the permissions:

```
docker run --user root lukasz619/light-core_server chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

This may work, depending on how you've set up the image. There is also a further complication from the VM running in-between.

Comment: I hope you understand my English, couse Im from Poland ;) I have added to my previous post content of Dockerfile. Yeah, I know that there are different users on host and container. I ran that command: *sudo chmod -R mysql:mysql mysql/* On container.. I ran it over SSH. That, what you posted is the same what I did, I think. After I built an image, I have connected to container through SSH and there I installed mysql, etc. When I have installed mysql, I checked if its working correctly (+ saved by *docker commit*), and then I started working on sharing /var/lib/mysql with my host.

Comment: You ran chmod, not chown. Containers don't normally use sudo or SSH, which is why I assumed you were working on the host.

Comment: I know, I forgot to write in my first post about SSH. And there was a typo - I meant Chown in my first post (not chmod) :) Chown dont work..

Comment: That can't be the Dockerfile - you haven't installed mysql or created a mysql user. I don't really like what you've done. It would be much better to use the official mysql and apache images than roll your own. You can use docker exec instead of SSH normally.